# Instance of 'ForeignKey' has no 'price' member

Tags: python, django

I get an error when i try to use the price and discount_price objects from the Equipment class in the EquipmentOrderItem class

here is the class in my models.py file

```
class EquipmentOrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    objects = models.Manager()


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.equipment.name}"

    def get_total_equipment_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.equipment.price

    def get_total_discount_equipment_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.equipment.discount_price
```

here is the class i want to get the object from

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery')
    description = models.TextField(default='about item')
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=3, default='VID')
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1, default='P')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    objects = models.Manager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('create:equipment_detail', kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
    })

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("create:add_to_cart", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("create:remove_from_cart", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
        })
```

this is where i am making the call from the template

```
   {% for equipment_order_item in object.equipments.all %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>{{ equipment_order_item.equipment.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ equipment_order_item.equipment.price }}</td>
                <td>{{ equipment_order_item.quantity }}</td>
                <td>
                {% if equipment_order_item.discount_price %}
                    #{{ equipment_order_item.quantity.get_total_discount_equipment_price }}
                    (Saving #{{ equipment_order_item.get_amount_saved }})
                {% else %}
                    #{{ equipment_order_item.quantity.get_total_equipment_price }}
                {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What error do you get? And what have to tried so far?

Comment: i am getting the instance of 'ForeignKey' has no 'price' member

Comment: i have tried hardcoding it in but it still didnt work

Comment: usage for this?

Comment: it is suppose to take those objects, run that subtraction and display the answer on a template but now its not displaying and i am sure it is because of the error

Comment: Have you ran python manage.py makemigrations and migrate successfully?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling these methods? And also add the full traceback?

Comment: When i try to run makemigrations is says no changes detected.

Comment: @Ivoredafe can you add the full traceback from the logs?

Comment: there aren't any tracebacks its just not working. the error is coming up on vscode

Comment: It's just a warning from your IDE? You need to install a Django plugin for vscode...

Comment: what is "object.equipments.all" where does "equipmentS" come from, don't you need something like "equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="equipments")" for use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #{{ equipment_order_item.quantity.get_total_discount_equipment_price }}
      (Saving #{{ equipment_order_item.get_amount_saved }})
 {% else %}
 #{{ equipment_order_item.quantity.get_total_equipment_price }}
```

This code tries to call the methods on the quantity field and not on the order item. Consider that python comments in templates are ignored by the rendering engine, the same is true for html- comments.

Try changing it to:

```
  #{{ equipment_order_item.get_total_discount_equipment_price }}
      (Saving #{{ equipment_order_item.get_amount_saved }})
 {% else %}
 #{{ equipment_order_item.get_total_equipment_price }}
```